# Sort tree by title Gedmo Tree Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, tree

I want to display my Categories tree sort by names. I have a CategoryType to create new Category entity and assignate it a parent Category with a select box. Here's my form type :

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', TextType::class, array("required" => false));
    $builder->add('parent', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'CAPShopAdminBundle:Category',
        'choice_label' => 'selectBoxName',
        'placeholder' => '-- Aucune --',
        'required' => false,
        'query_builder' => function(NestedTreeRepository $r) {
            return $r->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->orderBy('c.root, c.lvl, c.name', 'ASC');
        }
    ));
    $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class);
}
```

Here's the result :

[image]

I search this result :

[image]

Is it possible without PHP treatment, just with the good SQL query?

Comment: I think You just need to play with ordering a bit more.

Comment: Huh, as I said, I've tried everything I know...

Comment: Are you sure `->orderBy('c.root, c.lvl, c.name', 'ASC');` is correct? Have you tried it without `c.lvl` like `->orderBy('c.root, c.name', 'ASC');`?

Comment: c.lvl is required to assure the hierarchy of the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've find a solution. I've rebuild my tree with a start from one and only root node. This structure is better, and then, when I insert a node in the tree, I execute the reorder() function from Gedmo tree Bundle.

```
    /**
 * @param Category $category
 */
public function saveCategory(Category $category)
{

    if(!$category->getId()){ //insert
        $this->objectManager->persist($category);
        $this->objectManager->flush();

        $root = $this->categoryRepository->findOneBySlug('pieces-automobile'); //The root node
        $this->categoryRepository->reorder($root, 'name', 'ASC'); //Reoder by name
    }

    $category->setSlug($category->getId().'-'.$this->miscellaneous->slugify($category->getName(),'-'));

    $this->objectManager->flush();

}
```

My tree will be pretty small, maybe 30 nodes maximum. So I can reoder the tree each time I insert a node. But be careful, because reorder() is a heavy function who can takes some times with big tree.

I get my tree without the root with :

```
    /**
 * @return bool
 */
public function getAllCategories(){

    $root = $this->categoryRepository->findOneBySlug('pieces-automobile');

    $htmlTree = $this->categoryRepository->childrenHierarchy(
        $root, /* starting from root nodes */
        false, /* true to take only direct children */
        array(
            'decorate' => true,
            'representationField' => 'name',
            'html' => true,
        )
    );

    return $htmlTree;
}
```

And the result :

[image]