# Sort Gedmo Tree by arbitrary field using symfony3, doctrine2 and stofDoctrineExtensionsBundle

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, tree, symfony, stofdoctrineextensions

### Introduction

I am using:

- Windows 10 Pro
- XAMPP with PHP v7.0.9
- Symfony v3.1.7
- Doctrine v2.5.4
- StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle [[1]](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) in order to manage Tree structure.

### Setting up

To setup Tree structure I used documentation on Symfony.com [[2]](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html) followed by documentation on GitHub [[3]](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md). Then I proceeded with tree setup - used tree entity from example [[4]](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#tree-entity-example) and used code in [[5]](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#basic-usage-examples) to create a tree.

I did setup the tree structure (that represents directories and files) called `FileTree`. I added several custom fields to the tree: `item_name`, `item_extension` and `is_file`. Removed `title` as I have `item_name`...

My `FileTree` entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Table(name="file_tree")
 * use repository for handy tree functions
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FileTreeRepository")
 */
class FileTree
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1024)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $item_path;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=240)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $item_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $item_extension;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $is_file;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $lft;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $lvl;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRight
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $rgt;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FileTree")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $root;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeParent
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FileTree", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FileTree", mappedBy="parent")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"lft" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="file_tree")
     * @JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $project;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set itemPath
     *
     * @param string $itemPath
     *
     * @return FileTree
     */
    public function setItemPath($itemPath)
    {
        $this->item_path = $itemPath;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get itemPath
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getItemPath()
    {
        return $this->item_path;
    }

    /**
     * Set itemName
     *
     * @param string $itemName
     *
     * @return FileTree
     */
    public function setItemName($itemName)
    {
        $this->item_name = $itemName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get itemName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getItemName()
    {
        return $this->item_name;
    }

    /**
     * Set isFile
     *
     * @param boolean $isFile
     *
     * @return FileTree
     */
    public function setIsFile($isFile)
    {
        $this->is_file = $isFile;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isFile
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsFile()
    {
        return $this->is_file;
    }

    /**
     * Set lft
     *
     * @param integer $lft
     *
     * @return FileTree
     */
    public function setLft($lft)
    {
        $this->lft = $lft;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lft
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getLft()
    {
        return $this->lft;
    }

    /**
     * Set lvl
     *
     * @param integer $lvl
     *
     * @return FileTree
     */
    public function setLvl($lvl)
    {
        $this->lvl = $lvl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lvl
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getLvl()
    {
        return $this->lvl;
    }

    /**
     * Set rgt
     *
     * @param integer $rgt
     *
     * @return FileTree
     */
    public function setRgt($rgt)
    {
        $this->rgt = $rgt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rgt
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRgt()
    {
        return $this->rgt;
    }

    /**
     * Set root
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\FileTree $root
     *
     * @return FileTree
     */
    public function setRoot(\AppBundle\Entity\FileTree $root = null)
    {
        $this->root = $root;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get root
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\FileTree
     */
    public function getRoot()
    {
        return $this->root;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\FileTree $parent
     *
     * @return FileTree
     */
    public function setParent(\AppBundle\Entity\FileTree $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\FileTree
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Add child
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\FileTree $child
     *
     * @return FileTree
     */
    public function addChild(\AppBundle\Entity\FileTree $child)
    {
        $this->children[] = $child;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove child
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\FileTree $child
     */
    public function removeChild(\AppBundle\Entity\FileTree $child)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($child);
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * Set project
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Project $project
     *
     * @return FileTree
     */
    public function setProject(\AppBundle\Entity\Project $project = null)
    {
        $this->project = $project;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get project
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Project
     */
    public function getProject()
    {
        return $this->project;
    }

    /**
     * toString
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getItemName();
    }

    /**
     * Set itemExtension
     *
     * @param string $itemExtension
     *
     * @return FileTree
     */
    public function setItemExtension($itemExtension)
    {
        $this->item_extension = $itemExtension;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get itemExtension
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getItemExtension()
    {
        return $this->item_extension;
    }
}
```

### Problem

I need to order files in the folders of the tree by file type - that is: by `item_extension` and then by `item_name`. At the moment `Gedmo Nestedset Tree` sorts by `root` and `lft` as is shown in next code block.

```
public function getFileTreeNodeArray($file_tree_root_id)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('ft')
        ->from('AppBundle:FileTree', 'ft')
        ->where('ft.root = :root')
        ->setParameter('root', $file_tree_root_id)
        ->orderBy('ft.root, ft.lft', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

    $query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true);
    $build_my_tree = $query->getArrayResult();

    return $build_my_tree;
}
```

Sadly adding additional `->orderBy('ft.item_extension', 'ASC')` did not yield any results...

Then I learned [[6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537265/sort-tree-by-title-gedmo-tree-symfony) that there are 2 functions that may aide me in this endeavor `reorderAll` and `reorder`. I tried both of them, but sadly items did not change their order, they remained ordered by `root` and `lft`.

My code from `Upload Listener`:

```
$repo_file_tree = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:FileTree');
$root_node_id = $repo_file_tree->getFileTreeRootNodeIdByProjectId($selected_node_parent_id);
$root_node = $repo_file_tree->findOneBy(array('id' => $root_node_id));
$repo_file_tree->reorder($root_node, 'item_extension, item_name', 'ASC');
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

or

```
$repo_file_tree = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:FileTree');
$repo_file_tree->reorderAll('item_extension, item_name', 'ASC');
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

### Question

How do I get an array with `FileTree` items that are ordered by `item_extension, item_name`?

I would be happy with ether correct Doctrine query (preferably) or with explanation what is wrong with code blocks that contain functions `reorder` and `reorderAll`.

### Conclusion

What am I missing?

Please advise.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Comment: @xabbuh, as you commented in some of my previous questions, maybe you will find this one interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updated my project to `Symfony v3.2.0`

Now I get error

```
Invalid sort options specified: field - item_extension, item_name, direction - ASC
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

with above mentioned code when using `reorder`.

I am not sure is it occurring just now (after upgrade) or it was there also with `Symfony v3.1.x`.

Anyhow - it is clear that `reorder` does take only one field by which it orders tree branch. Not multiple fields as I tried earlier.

So the answer is: not to use several ordering fields when calling `reorder` function.

```
$repo_file_tree = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:FileTree');
$root_node_id = $repo_file_tree->getFileTreeRootNodeIdByProjectId($selected_node_parent_id);
$root_node = $repo_file_tree->findOneBy(array('id' => $root_node_id));
$repo_file_tree->reorder($root_node, 'item_extension', 'ASC');
$this->entityManager->flush();
```